# Prepare JBoss 7.1 For Web

Tags: jboss7.x

I have already made a web application in Java using JBoss 7.1.Within localhost everything is working fine.Now i want to put this application into the internet and i got several questions.

1. How do i configure JBoss 7.1 for web?
2. Do I need to put JBoss on a web server or do i have just to configure JBoss 7.1 and run it on any machine?

Can someone explain please..thx?
sdlfihasldifhuaslidfhasldifjhasdlifhasldifjhasldjfhasöjdfhasöjdfhaösjdfhöasjdfhaösdjfhöasjdfhöasjdfhöasdjfhöaskjfhösakjdfhösakjdfhöaskjdfhösakjfhösakjdfhöaskjdfhösakjdfhöaskjdfhöaskjdfhöaskjdfhösakjdfhöaskjdfhöaskjdfhöaskjdfhöaksjdfhösadkfhjösakdfhjöasdkfh

Answer (score 0):

First You will configure the JBoss As 7.1

Follow this link..

[JBoss 7.1 development issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897339/jboss-7-1-development-issues/21107215#21107215)